# mat-toolbar is not a known element

Tags: angular, typescript

i'm having a weird issue, i want to use **mat-toolbar** in a component (i'm already using mat-toolbar in another so the version of angular and material is, i think compatible) but the compiler have an error "mat-toolbar is not a known element".

here is a component who doesn't have any error about mat-toolbar :

```
<mat-toolbar class="app-toolbar py-2" color="primary">
    <div class="flex items-center">
        <img class="w-8 sm:mx-8 mx-3" src="assets/images/logo/L-logo-angle-brut.png">
        <span>{{'Home.HomePage.header_who_are_us' | transloco}}</span>
    </div>
    <a class="button-toolbar sm:mr-4 mr-0" mat-flat-button (click)="redirection()">
        <span>{{'Home.HomePage.header_beta' | transloco}}</span>
        <mat-icon class="ml-2 icon-size-5" [svgIcon]="'heroicons_solid:arrow-narrow-right'"></mat-icon>
    </a>
</mat-toolbar>
```

and his module :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Route, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { SharedModule } from 'app/shared/shared.module';
import { LandingHomeComponent } from 'app/modules/landing/home/home.component';
import { MatButtonToggleModule } from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatDividerModule } from '@angular/material/divider';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatProgressBarModule } from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import { FuseCardModule } from '@fuse/components/card';
import { MatCardModule } from "@angular/material/card";
import { landingHomeRoutes } from './home.routing';
import { MatToolbarModule } from "@angular/material/toolbar";
import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        LandingHomeComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(landingHomeRoutes),
        MatButtonModule,
        MatIconModule,
        SharedModule,
        MatButtonToggleModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,
        MatDividerModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatProgressBarModule,
        MatTooltipModule,
        FuseCardModule,
        SharedModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        MatGridListModule,
        TranslateModule
    ]
})
export class LandingHomeModule
{
}
```

and the one who trigger the error :

```
<div class="container">
    <mat-toolbar color="primary" class="main-toolbar">
        <span>Audio Player</span>
    </mat-toolbar>
</div>
```

and the module :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Route, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AudioPlayerComponent } from './audio-player.component';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatButtonToggleModule } from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatDividerModule } from '@angular/material/divider';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatProgressBarModule } from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import { FuseCardModule } from '@fuse/components/card';
import { SharedModule } from 'app/shared/shared.module';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';
import {MatSliderModule} from '@angular/material/slider';

const audioPlayerRoutes: Route[] = [
    {
        path     : '',
        component: AudioPlayerComponent
    }
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AudioPlayerComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(audioPlayerRoutes),
        MatButtonModule,
        MatButtonToggleModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,
        MatDividerModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatProgressBarModule,
        MatListModule,
        MatTooltipModule,
        FuseCardModule,
        MatSliderModule,
        SharedModule,
        MatCardModule,
        FlexLayoutModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        CommonModule,
    ],
    exports: [
        AudioPlayerComponent
    ]
})
export class AudioPlayerModule
{
}
```

the MatSliderModule and MatListModule have the same issue but i didn't past the code, i guess it's the same problem. i'm really stuck any help would be appreciated ...

Comment: can you tell if AudioPlayerModule is being correctly lazyloaded in parent module such as app.routing-module.ts?

Comment: yep it is, it's used in the footer of the website

Comment: Well, if all the modules dependecies are well configured, sometimes if you use VSCode, just closing and opening it removes the compilation errors you see in your templates (It has to do with language service)

Comment: yes true, i did that already... but it didn't solve the problem

Comment: i also tried to turn off my computer and put it in rice (i'm kidding) but it didn't solve anything

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
exports: [
        AudioPlayerComponent
    ]
```

also check whether you already included the tooltip related modules in `SharedModule`. If yes, then remove there.

Comment: it doesn't change anything with or without the exports unfortunately, and i have nothing about it in my sharedmodule